# Wireless not showing in Lubuntu 17.04 but wired connection works

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, broadcom, 17.04

**Data of the script: wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info**

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 01 Jun 2017 12:05 PDT -0700

Booted last: 01 Jun 2017 00:00 PDT -0700

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-21-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 28 16:13:17 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Lubuntu

##### lspci #############################

10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [103c:1508]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

30:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8042 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4357] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 88E8042 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [103c:308a]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b159 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:231d Hewlett-Packard Broadcom 2070 Bluetooth Combo
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
b43                   397312  0
bcma                   53248  1 b43
mac80211              700416  1 b43
cfg80211              532480  2 b43,mac80211
ssb                    57344  1 b43
wmi                    16384  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp48s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp48s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 10.28.34.9/24 brd 10.28.34.255 scope global dynamic enp48s0
       valid_lft 691190sec preferred_lft 691190sec
    inet6 fe80::af79:ab54:7c4d:5f38/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp48s0   no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 10.28.34.254 dev enp48s0 proto static metric 100 
10.7.0.4 via 10.28.34.254 dev enp48s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.28.34.0/24 dev enp48s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.28.34.9 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       490     1  0 12:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp48s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        88E8042 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         sky2
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.30
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp48s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:30:00.0/net/enp48s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp48s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       4defba7a-a98b-388f-b095-37b180cc3877
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   4defba7a-a98b-388f-b095-37b180cc3877 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.28.34.9/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.28.34.254
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.7.0.4/32, nh = 10.28.34.254, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.1.1.7
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.7.0.4
IP4.DNS[3]:                             10.21.40.181
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          whitworth.edu
IP4.WINS[1]:                            10.1.1.7
IP4.WINS[2]:                            10.7.0.4
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 10.1.1.7 10.7.0.4 10.21.40.181
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 10.28.34.9
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 10.7.0.4
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        netbios_name_servers = 10.1.1.7 10.7.0.4
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       broadcast_address = 10.28.34.255
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 604800
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       routers = 10.28.34.254
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 345600
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       domain_name = whitworth.edu
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       expiry = 1497035112
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 10.28.34.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 691200
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::af79:ab54:7c4d:5f38/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Los_Angeles (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp48s0   no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp48s0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[b43]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     5F955FFEA61C80144A2B433
depends:        mac80211,ssb,bcma,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload 686 
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     C645ADA4C8790A787B7C8E9
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload 686 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-21-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     25AD08C8BBFD528CC9B45E2
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload 686 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-21-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D77C8F93375950F3BA95B16
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload 686 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[ssb]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     38B7A1BE5CF467C3CF164D5
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload 686 

##### module parameters #################

[b43]
allhwsupport: 0
bad_frames_preempt: 0
btcoex: 1
hwpctl: 0
hwtkip: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
pio: 0
qos: 1
verbose: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/libpisock9.conf]
blacklist visor

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  315.989205] sky2 0000:30:00.0 enp48s0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex, flow control rx
[  315.989235] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp48s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to uninstall and then re-install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package.

First open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then re-start the laptop.